# Ionic.Zip library unable to extract .rar file C#

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

I am trying to extract .rar file using .net zip library (Ionic.Zip.dll). I got error "**cannot read that as a zipfile**" while executing following code;

```
using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read("E:\\APPS\\package.rar")){
}
```

I know the error is self explanatory but documentation of Ionic.Zip says that it can be used to extract .rar files. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you see it in the documentation? I just looked at the FAQ: "Can DotNetZip read or write RAR files? No. DotNetZip does zip files."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I not found anywhere in description that `DotNetZip` can extract `rar` files. He can extract `zip` created with `WinRAR` but nowhere notice `rar` file can be extracted.

[DotNetZip - Zip and Unzip in C#, VB, any .NET language](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

But, there is something interesting (link bellow) :

[SharpCompress - a fully native C# library for RAR, 7Zip, Zip, Tar, GZip, BZip2](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/)