# Extracting .rar Files in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an auto update function for a little Tool i'm making. I got to the point when it downloads the .rar file, but now i have to extract this .rar file. For this i'm using Ionic.Zip(A Refference), like this:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Tool[" + Program.newVersion + "].rar");
zipFile.ExtractAll(Application.StartupPath);
```

But when running this it gives me a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocation" Exception... Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong or has another solution for extracting.rar files!?

Comment: A ZIP file !=RAR; you need to use a library specific for RAR files or some other file management library; [Ionic.Zip does not support RAR files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382210/ionic-zip-library-unable-to-extract-rar-file-c-sharp).

Answer (score -3):

DotNetZip / Ionic does not support .rar files:

> Can DotNetZip read or write RAR files?
>
> No. DotNetZip does zip files.

- http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

You can use something like [SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) though, which does support .rar files among other extensions.

Comment: People vote based on usefulness. Answers on duplicates (unless they're of extraordinary quality) are generally more harm than good. Hence the downvotes. Removing the post is not required, but then again, neither is removing any of the votes. I'm temporarily locking this post to prevent the extended discussion in comments. If you wish to contest the votes or the decisions made by me or other members of the community, feel free to post on [meta].